# React Native: Align text to the left but placeholder to the right

Tags: reactjs, react-native, placeholder, textinput

I'm working on a React Native application and I'm facing an issue with aligning a text input and its placeholder differently. I want the input text to be aligned to the right, while keeping the placeholder aligned to the left within the same input field. I've tried using the `textAlign` property, but it's affecting both the input text and the placeholder. Here's the code I've tried:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        value={text}
        onChangeText={setText}
        placeholder="Placeholder"
        placeholderTextColor="gray"
        textAlign="right" // This affects both input text and placeholder
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  textInput: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default MyComponent;
```

How can I achieve the desired effect of aligning the input text to the right while keeping the placeholder text aligned to the left?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can use a Text as the placeholder along with the TextInput and manipulate the Text in the style make the TextInput a position : relative and the Text position: absolute and position it on the right side of the textInput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of styling in react-native it's similar to React per se, I believe what you are trying to achieve is something like this:

```
 return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      value={inputValue}
      onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
    />
  
      <Text style={styles.placeholder}>Placeholder</Text>
    
  </View>
</View>
);
```

and the styles will be like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textInputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
  },
  placeholder: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 15,
    color: 'gray',
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})
```

You can use the Text and make it as the placeholder of the TextInput and just manipulate the style.

Comment: This approach has a flaw. Which is, in most of the cases, when placeholder is longer, i.e. "Enter your phone" and when a user clicks on this text. The text field won't be focused. To make the text field get focused, user needs to click on somewhere blank. i.e. outside of our Text component @Rey

Comment: well you need to tweak a little more by using onblur or onfocus something like that hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know, if there is any native way to style the placeholder differently in React Native. But since you update the State, as soon as text is entered, you can react on that and change the alignment:

```
textAlign={text.length > 0 ? "right" : "left"}
```

Comment: I tried this solution already as well but it does not look professional or seems like a patch. The text is align to the left. As I enter a character, for fractions of seconds, it is align to the left then it moves to the right. Hence it looks bad.

Comment: In that case, try the method that Rey suggested in the comments. It's more complicated but may suit your need. In the future, please be sure to provide the solutions you already tried in the first place ;-)